# Concrete class specific methods

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

I have an interesting problem.  Consider this class hierachy:

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual float GetMember( void ) const =0;
   virtual void SetMember( float p ) =0;
};

class ConcreteFoo : public Base
{
public:
   ConcreteFoo( "foo specific stuff here" );

   virtual float GetMember( void ) const;
   virtual void SetMember( float p );

   // the problem
   void foo_specific_method( "arbitrary parameters" );
};

Base* DynamicFactory::NewBase( std::string drawable_name );

// it would be used like this
Base* foo = dynamic_factory.NewBase("foo");
```

I've left out the DynamicFactory definition and how Builders are
registered with it.  The Builder objects are associated with a name
and will allocate a concrete implementation of Base.  The actual
implementation is a bit more complex with shared_ptr to handle memory
reclaimation, but they are not important to my problem.

`ConcreteFoo` has class specific method.  But since the concrete instances
are create in the dynamic factory the concrete classes are not known or
accessible, they may only be declared in a source file.  How can I
expose `foo_specific_method` to users of `Base*`?

I'm adding the solutions I've come up with as answers.  I've named
them so you can easily reference them in your answers.

I'm not just looking for opinions on my original solutions, new ones
would be appreciated.

Comment: Please make your answers community wiki answers!  Thanks.

Comment: Or, remove your answers entirely.  Though I guess this could work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast would be faster than most other solutions, however:

in Base Class add:

```
void passthru( const string &concreteClassName, const string &functionname, vector<string*> args )
{
    if( concreteClassName == className )
         runPassThru( functionname, args );
}

private:
    string className;
    map<string, int> funcmap;
    virtual void runPassThru( const string &functionname, vector<string*> args ) {}
```

in each derived class:

```
void runPassThru( const string &functionname, vector<string*> args )
{
   switch( funcmap.get( functionname ))
   {
      case 1:
          //verify args
          // call function
        break;
      // etc..
   }
}

// call in constructor
void registerFunctions()
{
      funcmap.put( "functionName", id );
      //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CrazyMetaType` solution.

This solution is not well thought out.  I was hoping someone might
have had experience with something similar.  I saw this applied to the
problem of an unknown number of a known type.  It was pretty slick.  I
was thinking to apply it to an unkown number of unknown type***S***

The basic idea is the CrazyMetaType collects the parameters is type
safe way, then executing the concrete specific method.

```
class Base
{
   ...
   virtual CrazyMetaType concrete_specific( int kind ) =0;
};

// used like this
foo->concrete_specific(foo_method_id) << "foo specific" << foo_specific;
```

My one worry with this solution is that `CrazyMetaType` is going to be
insanely complex to get this to work.  I'm up to the task, but I
cannot count on future users to be up to be c++ experts just to add
one concrete specific method.

Answer (score 0):

Add special functions to `Base`.

The simplest and most unacceptable solution is to add
foo_specific_method to `Base`.  Then classes that don't
use it can just define it to be empty.  This doesn't work because
users are allowed to registers their own Builders with the
dynamic_factory.  The new classes may also have concrete class
specific methods.

In the spirit of this solution, is one slightly better.  Add generic
functions to `Base`.

```
class Base
{
   ...
   /// \return true if 'kind' supported
   virtual bool concrete_specific( int kind, "foo specific parameters" );
};
```

The problem here is there maybe quite a few overloads of
concrete_specific for different parameter sets.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it.

When a foo specific method is needed, generally you know that the
`Base*` is actually a `ConcreteFoo`.  So just ensure the definition of class
`ConcreteFoo` is accessible  and:

```
ConcreteFoo* foo2 = dynamic_cast<ConcreteFoo*>(foo);
```

One of the reasons I don't like this solution is dynamic_casts are slow and
require RTTI.

The next step from this is to avoid dynamic_cast.

```
ConcreteFoo* foo_cast( Base* d )
{
   if( d->id() == the_foo_id )
   {
      return static_cast<ConcreteFoo*>(d);
   }

   throw std::runtime_error("you're screwed");
}
```

This requires one more method in the Base class which is completely
acceptable, but it requires the id's be managed.  That gets difficult
when users can register their own Builders with the dynamic factory.

I'm not too fond of any of the casting solutions as it requires the
user classes to be defined where the specialized methods are used.
But maybe I'm just being a scope nazi.

Comment: Would +1 if community wiki (see comments on question).  Using an id system is just what RTTI does (though RTTI provides a safer method and implements things differently).

Comment: I agree.  If you are worried about the performance of dynamic_cast (I wouldn't be), do some tests.  Unless you are doing this in a tight loop, I can't imagine that it would be that expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The `cstdarg` solution.

Bjarn Stroustrup said:

> A well defined program needs at most few functions for which the
>   argument types are not completely specified. Overloaded functions and
>   functions using default arguments can be used to take care of type
>   checking in most cases when one would otherwise consider leaving
>   argument types unspecified. Only when both the number of arguments and
>   the type of arguments vary is the ellipsis necessary

```
class Base
{
   ...
   /// \return true if 'kind' supported
   virtual bool concrete_specific( int kind, ... ) =0;
};
```

The disadvantages here are:

- almost no one knows how to use cstdarg correctly
- it doesn't feel very c++-y
- it's not typesafe.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create other non-concrete subclasses of Base and then use multiple factory methods in DynamicFactory?

Your goal seems to be to subvert the point of subclassing. I'm really curious to know what you're doing that requires this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the concrete object has a class-specific method then it implies that you'd only be calling that method specifically when you're dealing with an instance of that class and not when you're dealing with the generic base class.  Is this coming about b/c you're running a switch statement which is checking for object type?

I'd approach this from a different angle, using the "unacceptable" first solution but with no parameters, with the concrete objects having member variables that would store its state.  Though i guess this would force you have a member associative array as part of the base class to avoid casting to set the state in the first place.

You might also want to try out the Decorator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something akin to the `CrazyMetaType` or the cstdarg argument but simple and C++-ish.  (Maybe this could be `SaneMetaType`.)  Just define a base class for arguments to `concrete_specific`, and make people derive specific argument types from that.  Something like

```
class ConcreteSpecificArgumentBase;

class Base
{
   ...  
   virtual void concrete_specific( ConcreteSpecificArgumentBase &argument ) =0;
};
```

Of course, you're going to need RTTI to sort things out inside each version of `concrete_specific`.  But if `ConcreteSpecificArgumentBase` is well-designed, at least it will make calling `concrete_specific` fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The weird part is that the users of your DynamicFactory receive a Base type, but needs to do specific stuff when it is a ConcreteFoo.

Maybe a factory should not be used.

Try to look at other dependency injection mechanisms like creating the ConcreteFoo yourself, pass a ConcreteFoo type pointer to those who need it, and a Base type pointer to the others.

Answer (score 0):

The context seems to assume that the user will be working with your ConcreteType and know it is doing so.

In that case, it seems that you could have another method in your factory that returns ConcreteType*, if clients know they're dealing with concrete type and need to work at that level of abstraction.